# Hyperforce, how to test before transition date?

Tags: hyperforce

My client received the [Hyperforce](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=Introducing-Hyperforce-General-Information-FAQ&language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=1#:%7E:text=What%20is%20Hyperforce%3F,meet%20local%20data%20storage%20requirements.) email that they are being moved soon. We wish to test the URL's used by external API's using the Tenant Specific Endpoints format to make sure that all is converted correctly and works. How to do this? Will the old server exist in parallel with the new so one can test and revert back if things break? Or is it a turn key process where on that date one checks to see what works and what doesn't (not recommended). Does anyone know how the process works as far as testing and verifying all will work?

Comment: I would have thought that the best way to address these questions is to get in touch with your (or your client's) Salesforce Account Manager.

Comment: I opened up a ticket and await a reply. I was hoping someone would know sooner as I have others who await a reply from me.

Comment: Have you reviewed [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000363860&type=1)

Comment: (@Swetha I assumed the OP had since the document they referenced in the question contains multiple links to this article.)

Comment: I wouldn't use Salesforce Support for this (in the first instance) - better to contact your account manager first and get their guidance. Or post a question on the Partner Forums (if you are a partner).